# Add users in batches

Tags: java, mailchimp

I tried adding members using Java library ecwid and using post request and I am able to do that but I am not getting how we can add members in batches using API.
V3.0 of API has not implemented batch operation as yet. What about V2.0, somebody is able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In v2.0, the call you're looking for is [`batchSubscribe()`](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/batch-subscribe.php).